# Fund transfer from scamner's account to my account

Tags: mutual-funds, transfer

Someone scamed another and their scammer transfer some amount to my account from his account for car purchase. I am not aware he is a scammer untill police started their investigation. Does this make me an accomplice? Am l answerable to him crime?

Comment: Hello, you question is way too unclear. Who scammed whom? Who transferred money to your account? Who purchased the car? Who sold the car? How did you come into the picture? Why did they transfer money to your account?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this make me an accomplice?

The police might think you are.  How much effort you'll have to make to show otherwise depends on what country you're in and how suspicious the police are of you.

> Am l answerable to him crime?

Only if the police and prosecutor think that you are guilty (or, sadly, if all they care about is a "win", and don't care if an innocent person is convicted).

Definitely speak to a lawyer!!